# Calculation of duration based on spot rates

Tags: duration

As I know, Macaulay and modified durations are defined in terms of yield to maturity (YTM), in other words, in order to calculate durations we use yield to maturity as a discount factor. 
Suppose, that instead of YTM we want to calculate durations based on spot rates. Should I calculate Macaulay duration in the following way:$$MacD=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{n}tCF_t/(1+s_t)^t}{\sum_{t=1}^{n}CF_t/(1+s_t)^t},$$ where $s_t$ is spot rate (zero-coupon rate) for period $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, definitely, see [definition of Macaulay duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_duration)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have considered the attached article about duration, but, unfortunately, I didn't find something about duration calculation based on spot rates.

Comment: The fact that the definition refers to the $PV_i$, i.e. the present values of each single cashflow, requires that you use spot rates. If you used yields, the $PV_i$ would not be correct

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: When you use the spot rates it is called the Fisher-Weil duration http://www.bondtutor.com/btchp6/topic6/topic6.htm Macaulay used ytm's in his work.

Comment: @Alex C: Interestingly, Wikipedia seems to suggest otherwise

Comment: Wikipedia: "Fisher–Weil duration is a refinement of Macaulay’s duration which takes into account the term structure of interest rates. Fisher–Weil duration calculates the present values of the relevant cashflows (more strictly) by using the zero coupon yield for each respective maturity."

Comment: right - had missed that, apologies

Comment: @AlexC Thank you for you comment. As I see from the link that you provided, my formula is correct, but it isn't called Macaulay duration, istead Fisher-Weil duration (if I am wrong, please let me know). And what about modified duration? What is the generalization of modified duration and how it is defined? Thank you.